# Create event daily, on a specific time

Tags: events, mysql-event

**First event deletes all rows from a table:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`frontdes_user`@`localhost` EVENT `DELETE_flux_receptie` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-06 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE FROM `flux_receptie`
```

**Second event deletes the `id` column from the same table:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`frontdes_user`@`localhost` EVENT `delete_id` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-06 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO ALTER TABLE `flux_receptie` DROP `id`
```

**Third event adds `id` column into the same table:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`frontdes_user`@`localhost` EVENT `add_id` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-06 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO ALTER TABLE `flux_receptie` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I want these events to run daily:
First one daily at 06:30, the second one daily at 06:35 and the third daily at 06:40.
Can anyone help me please with the correct schedule? Best regards, Bogdan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your machine you can use cronJob, the basic format of a crontab schedule consists of 6 fields, placed on a single line and separated by spaces, formatted as follows:

```
minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute
```

first create a script:

**First script**

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[db name] --execute="CREATE DEFINER=`frontdes_user`@`localhost` EVENT `DELETE_flux_receptie` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-06 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE FROM `flux_receptie`"
```

**Second script**

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[db name] --execute="CREATE DEFINER=`frontdes_user`@`localhost` EVENT `delete_id` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-06 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO ALTER TABLE `flux_receptie` DROP `id`"
```

**Third script**

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=[username] --password=[password] --database=[db name] --execute="ALTER TABLE `flux_receptie` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
```

then create 3 cron using `crontab -e`

## crontab -e

30 6 * * * /path/of/scriptOne

35 6 * * * /path/of/scriptTwo

40 6 * * * /path/of/scriptThree

Comment: cronJob is a program? Yes I have access. It`s on my wamp server.

Comment: I don't know how it works on windows but the name is schtasks using the command line utility. Sorry but i suppose you are on linux machine

Comment: I have an Event scheduler in phpmyadmin. There I should work it out.

Comment: Yeah you can also use the phpMyAdmin event scheduler, fill all the field. If you have problem write here

Comment: Thanks, it was easy enough with PHPMyadmin Event Scheduler.